# Can someone explain this piece of angularjs directive code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, parameter-passing

I come from stricter languages such as Java, C#, C++ and have been using this code to read file into textarea without understanding how it worked due to time issue. Now I'm trying to learn directives so I can understand this directive, but I'm having difficulty understanding one part of this code.

This is my controller's function that I'm expected to get called. fileContent is just a string of texts:

```
self.displayFileContent = function(contents) {
    self.fileContent = contents;
};
```

This is the implementation for the read file directive. I'm expecting the call to be `displayFileContentFn(fileContents)` but why is it calling the function with completely different parameters (and different number of parameters)? is {'contents : filecontents } an javascript object here?

```
scope: false,
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('change', function(e) {

            var displayFileContentFn = $parse(attrs.onFileChange);
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function() {
                var fileContents = reader.result;

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    displayFileContentFn(scope, {
                        'contents' : fileContents
                    });
                });
            };
            reader.readAsText(element[0].files[0]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide scope part of your directive.i.e scope : {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has something to do with angular's $parse service.

if you bind the on-file-change attribute like:

```
on-file-change='displayFileContent(content)'
```

The displayFileContenFn defined by:

```
var displayFileContentFn = $parse(attrs.onFileChange);
```

is in fact giving something like (the real code are much more complicated here i just simplified it to make it easy to understand):

```
var displayFileContentFn = function(scope,parameters){
     var contents = parameters['contents'];
     scope.displayFileContent(contents);
}
```

So here

```
displayFileContentFn(scope, {
                        'contents' : fileContents
                    });
```

means that use the `scope` to execute the `displayFileContent` (because we bound it to on-file-change attribute), passing the fileContents as the `contents` parameter (which we declared it in the attribute as the first parameter).

In this way, the fileContents read will be passed to the `displayFileContent` function as the `contents` when the reader finishes reading.

Comment: Thanks, this simplify version helps clear it up. The 'contents' from `{ 'contents' : fileContents }` must match the name of the parameter in `displayFileContent(contents)`, correct? or is it matching the name somewhere else? I tried `'dummy'` and it failed.

Comment: Yes they must match. You may think that the $parse service provided by angular is kinda parser to parse the string expression into real javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on here, you have to understand a bit about how angular's lifecycle works.

Essentially, you are providing an expression, not a function, to `$scope.$apply`.  That expression is executed using `$scope.$eval`, allowing the expression to be evaluated against a supplied `scope`. (In this case, the `scope` is defined by the directive)  After the expression has been evaluated, any exception handling is dealt with, then any watches can be fired.

**Pseudo-Code of $apply()**

```
function $apply(expr) {
  try {
    return $eval(expr);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  } finally {
    $root.$digest();
  }
}
```

In the case of your function, if your HTML is `on-file-change='displayFileContent(contents)'`, `$scope.$apply()` is taking in

```
displayFileContentFn(scope, {
    'contents' : fileContents
});
```

and getting back `displayFileContent(fileContents)`, where `displayFileContentFn == onFileChange` from the HTML, and `contents == fileContents` from the JavaScript function. This is then executed.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. My question was why `displayFileContentFn()` was called with 2 arguments instead of 1. Not on the $apply.

Comment: How can it be? `displayFileContentFn(arg1, arg2)` was passed to `apply` at which point it already had 2 arguments. All it did was simply calling a function with already 2 arguments in it, did it not?